# Extract data from a string that is between hex values

Tags: python

I have a list that only contains one string with hex values like \x01, \x02 ...
These hex values never occur at the beginning and never at the end of the string.

```
list1 = ["Test String\x01111\x05Test String\x02GG\x01TEXT123"]
```

I would like to extract all data in that string that is between hex values. So the data I want to extract is: `Test String`, `111`, `Test String`, `GG`, `TEXT123`.
How can I do that?

Please note, there can also be "empty data":

```
                         # between \x01 and \x05 is nothing
list2 = ["Test String\x01\x05Test String2"]
                         # this should be saved even it is ""
```

The output in this example should be: `Test String`, `EMPTY STRING` (I mean " "), `Test String2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.split), which behaves similarly to `str.split`, but uses a regular expression (rather than a string) as a separator.

When you say "hex value", I assume you mean "nonprintable ASCII character", i.e. in the range `0x00` to `0x1F` plus `0x7F`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('[\x00-\x1f\x7f]', 'Test String\x01111\x05Test String\x02GG\x01TEXT123')
['Test String', '111', 'Test String', 'GG', 'TEXT123']
>>> re.split('[\x00-\x1f\x7f]', 'Test String\x01\x05Test String2')
['Test String', '', 'Test String2']
```

Comment: thanks, that is perfect. I tried the normal `split()` function first, but re.split is nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here to group all the items that fall in ASCII printable range and for items in non-printable range if their group length is greater than 1 then return `''`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def solve(s):                                           
    for k, g in groupby(s, lambda x: 32 <= ord(x) < 127):
        if k:
            yield ''.join(g)
        else:
            g = list(g)
            if len(g) > 1:
                yield ''
...                 
>>> s = "Test String\x01111\x05Test String\x02GG\x01TEXT123"
>>> list(solve(s))                           
['Test String', '111', 'Test String', 'GG', 'TEXT123']
>>> s = "Test String\x01\x05Test String2"    
>>> list(solve(s))
['Test String', '', 'Test String2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re    
>>> re.findall(r'[\x01-\x05]([^\x01-\x05]*)[\x01-\x05]', list1[0])
['111', 'GG']
```

Your spec for "hex values like \x01, \x02 ..." is a bit ambiguous -- I'm assuming for the sake of the above snippet "values between \x01 and \x05 included" -- if you need a different range of "hex values" that's easy to adjust of course.

The key idea is to locate "one `hex value`, then zero or more `non-hex values`, then one `hex value`", and get the central "zero or more" part by enclosing it in parentheses, thus making it a **group** in the regular expression.  This way, `findall` will return a list of all the groups' contents, which appears to meet your request.